# Dynamic predicate in where clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the below search all fields condition where I specify the column names(Col1,Col2,Col3) I want the column names to be dynamic values which is in a different string array. How is that possible ?

rows is a list of EnumerableRowCollection rows which contains all data and then i apply the contains filter which will filter out the rows which contains the value in objSearch.SearchAllFields

```
if (objSearch.SearchAllFields != "")
                {
                    rows = results.Where(x => new[]
                                           { x.Field<string>("Col1"),
                                             x.Field<string>("Col2"),
                                             x.Field<string>("Col3")
                                           }.Any(s => s.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(objSearch.SearchAllFields.ToLowerInvariant())));
                }
```

something like given below which is wrong and doesnt work i know that.

```
string[] AllColumns = objProp.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
                if (objSearch.SearchAllFields != "")
                {
                    rows = results.Where(x => AllColumns.Any(s => s.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(objSearch.SearchAllFields.ToLowerInvariant())));
                }
```

Original

```
Col1     Col2    Col3 
test     abc    pqr
2        abc    123
asd      test    xyz
```

Expected

```
Col1     Col2    Col3 
test     abc    pqr
asd      test    xyz
```

Comment: Can you provide us an example? What will be an input and what is expected output

Comment: So rows is a list of  EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> rows which contains all data and then i apply the contains filter which will filter out the rows which contains the value in objSearch.SearchAllFields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried to change from

```cs
new[]
{ x.Field<string>("Col1"),
  x.Field<string>("Col2"),
  x.Field<string>("Col3")
}.Any(...
```

To this:

```cs
AllColumns.Any(...
```

Assuming `AllColumns` is `IEnumerable<string>`, I believe this would be the right solution:

```cs
rows = results.Where(row => AllColumns.Select(column => row.Field<string>(column)).Any(...
```

Comment: Thank you this has worked. You are the besttttt :)